# how can I convert 2020-05-14 14:16:36.000 to date?

Tags: mysql

I have a string like "2020-05-14 14:16:36.000"  I want to convert this string to this form "2020-05-14" but I cannot find "14:16:36.000" 000 mean in this part.

I must find this part because I want to use str_to_date function in mysql.

Thank you for your helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DATE_FORMAT()` function for your purpose.

#### Syntax :

```
DATE_FORMAT(date, format)
```

Here, `date` is the date string to be formatted and `format` specifies the format in which you want the output to be.

---

The following command will do your job -

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2020-05-14 14:16:36.000', '%D %M %Y');
```

Output : `14th May 2020`

You can use the following command if you want it in the format - `YYYY-MM-DD` :

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2020-05-14 14:16:36.000', '%Y-%m-%d');
```

Output : `2020-05-14`

The `DATE_FORMAT()` will strip convert the given string into date format which you mention as the second parameter. You can refer more about dates - [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)